# Is it possible to make a column in a list link to dispForm.aspx?

Tags: list-form, list-view, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to make a column in a list link to dispForm.aspx?

I know I can add LinkToItem="TRUE" to the fieldref in SPD2010, but its the Display Form, not the Edit Form that I want to link to. How can I do this?

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, you could use a basic workflow in SPD to update a URL field with the link to the item.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply.  Do you have any more specific information on how I would actually do that? I's have to update the url field with an ID wouldn't I?